# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'listen') when testing with Jest, Supertest, Express, Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, jestjs, supertest

**Problem:**

when running jest and supertest, i get an error before it reaches the actual tests i've described. Server runs fine using the start script, app is defined. But when running test script, app is undefined.

**Background:**

- I'm fairly new to typescript and this is the first time I'm using any kind of testing.
- I want to seperate the server instance, as seen on several blog posts and tutorials, as i plan on running multiple tests in different files.

If you have any suggestions even if they are something I already tried, ill try again and let you know. I am at my wits end so any help is much apprecitated. Thank you.

**Error:**

```
 FAIL  src/components/users/user.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'listen')

       6 |
       7 | dbConnection();
    >  8 | export const server = app.listen(config.server.port, () => {
         |                           ^
       9 |     logger.info(`Server is running on port: ${config.server.port}`);
      10 | });
      11 |

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/index.ts:8:27)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/library/exitHandler/exitHandler.ts:2:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/library/errorHandler/errorHandler.ts:2:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/middleware/validateSchema.ts:3:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/users/routes.ts:2:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/server.ts:2:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/users/user.test.ts:2:1)
```

*user.test.ts*

```
import request from 'supertest';
import app from '../../server';

describe('User registration', () => {
    it('POST /register --> return new user instance', async () => {
        await request(app)           // error occurs when reaching this point
            .post('/user/register')
            .send({
                firstName: 'Thomas',
                lastName: 'Haek',
                email: 'thomashaek@gmail.com',
                password: '12345678aA',
                confirmPassword: '12345678aA'
            })
            .expect(201)
            .then((response) => {
                expect(response.body).toEqual(
                    expect.objectContaining({
                        _id: expect.any(String),
                        firstName: expect.any(String),
                        lastName: expect.any(String),
                        email: expect.any(String),
                        token: expect.any(String)
                    })
                );
            });
    });
});
```

*server.ts*

```
import express, { Application } from 'express';
import userRouter from './components/users/routes';
import { routeErrorHandler } from './middleware/errorHandler';
import httpLogger from './middleware/httpLogger';
import './process';

const app: Application = express();

app.use(httpLogger);
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/user', userRouter);
app.use(routeErrorHandler);

export default app
```

*index.ts*

```
import { createHttpTerminator } from 'http-terminator';
import config from './config/config';
import dbConnection from './config/dbConnection';
import logger from './library/logger';
import app from './server'

dbConnection();
export const server = app.listen(config.server.port, () => {
    logger.info(`Server is running on port: ${config.server.port}`);
});

export const httpTerminator = createHttpTerminator({ server });
```

*package.json scripts*

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "env-cmd -f ./src/config/test.env jest --watchAll",
    "start": "env-cmd -f ./src/config/dev.env node build/index.js",

  },
```

*tsconfig.json*

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./build",
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "strict": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

*jest.config.ts*

```
import { Config } from 'jest';

/** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
const config: Config = {
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    testEnvironment: 'node',
    roots: ['./src'],
    moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'ts'],
    clearMocks: true,
    collectCoverage: true,
    coverageDirectory: 'coverage',
    coveragePathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', '/src/config/'],
    coverageProvider: 'v8',
    coverageReporters: ['json', 'text', 'lcov', 'clover'],
    verbose: true
};

export default config;
```

*exitHandler.ts*

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { httpTerminator, server } from '../..';


import logger from '../logger';

class ExitHandler {
    public async handleExit(code: number, timeout = 5000): Promise<void> {
        try {
            logger.info(`Attempting graceful shutdown with code: ${code}`);
            setTimeout(() => {
                logger.info(`Forcing a shutdown with code: ${code}`);
                process.exit(code);
            }, timeout).unref();

            if (server.listening) {
                logger.info('Terminating HTTP connections');
                await httpTerminator.terminate();
                await mongoose.connection.close();
            }
            logger.info(`Exiting gracefully with code ${code}`);
            process.exit(code);
        } catch (error) {
            logger.error(error);
            logger.error(
                `Unable to shutdown gracefully... Forcing exit with code: ${code}`
            );
            process.exit(code);
        }
    }
}

export const exitHandler = new ExitHandler();
```

**Things I've tried:**

- using the same env files for both test and server script (same error)
- messing around with the tsconfig and jest config files (same error)
- using module.exports = app instead of export default app or export const server = app (same error)
- commenting out all the middleware and routes and just exporting the app (same error)

Comment: For some reason it seems like jest is importing the `index.ts` file.
I do recall that jest suggests ordering the `moduleFileExtensions` by what is mostly used. In your case, `.ts` files should come before the `.js` extension.

See: https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#modulefileextensions-arraystring

If that doesn't help would you kindly create a github repo that reproduces this error?

Comment: Hi, I've changed `moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'ts']` to `moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'js']` and I still get the same error. I will create a public GitHub repo tonight that has the error if there is no solution by then. Thank you!

Comment: I see that hackape already answered below and I think that his answer is correct :)

Comment: I’d like to say, your post is a textbook example of what a good stackoverflow question should be like, which I don’t often see these days. Even more rare to see it from a new member, kudos! Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is caused by circular dependency. From the error stack

```
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/index.ts:8:27)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/library/exitHandler/exitHandler.ts:2:1
  …
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/server.ts:2:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/users/user.test.ts:2:1)
```

I see that `server.ts` deps on `exitHandler.ts` which in turn deps on `index.ts`. But in `index.ts` you `import app from './server'` forming a circle.

More specifically, in order for `app` from `server.ts` to be created, it needs `exitHandler`, but that thing needs `index`, and `index` needs `server`. It’s like recursion without a base case return. Unlike indefinite function recursion, dependency resolution will just give you `app` as `undefined`.

Thus you need to break the circle. Use some dependency injection trick to break the tie between `exitHandler` and `index` will do.

If you don’t know how to do that, post the `exitHandler.ts` code and I’ll follow up.

---

Instead of `import { httpTerminator, server } from '../..';` try this:

```
let server, httpTerminator;

export function injectDependency(s, h) {
  server = s;
  httpTerminator = h;
}
```

Now in `index.ts`

```
import { injectDependency } from "…/exitHandler"

injectDependency(server, httpTerminator);
```

Comment: Hi, I see what you're saying and that is something I thought about as well but at the same time, I tried commenting out all the middleware from the `server.ts` file and still got the error. That should've stopped any dependency recursion no? I added the `exitHandler.ts` file to the post. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Updated, try and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped me pass the `request(app)` portion of my test after so long!! Unfortunately, I'm now hitting a timeout error on my test but I shall continue to debug and create another post if needed.